# How to assign typescript variable to any attribute value?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-bind

I have a variable in my typescript file

```
public variableName: something;
```

I want to use this variable to replace custom attribute value in html code

```
<input type="radio" name="someName" id="someId" data-start-time="{{variableName}}" data-end-time="{{variableName}}">
```

data-start-time and data-end-time as custom attribute and i want their values to be replaced by typescript variable ( Angular) ??

---

**Edit--**

Adding More realistic Example--

```
public selectedWorkOrder: WorkOrder;
```

workOrder is interface having couple of variables ( eg, ID, title)

`<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1" data-start-time="{{selectedWorkOrder?.window1StartTime}}" data-end-time="{{selectedWorkOrder?.window1endTime}}">`
here trying to set object variables to attribute

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `[attr.data-start-time]="variableName"`

Comment: I'll give more details,
let say variableName = "done",
but done is not getting replaced at html input tag

Comment: Should work fine. Probably something going on. Show more (actual) code.

Comment: ``` public selectedWorkOrder: WorkOrder; ```
workOrder is interface having couple of variables ( eg, ID, title)

--------------------------

```               
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1" data-start-time="{{selectedWorkOrder?.window1StartTime}}" data-end-time="{{selectedWorkOrder?.window1endTime}}"> 
``` 

here trying to set object variables to attribute

Comment: @KamleshSilag, using an object is the same `[attr.data-start-time]="selectedWorkOrder?.window1StartTime"`. See that you use `[` `]` and use between the quotes the "variable"

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? With both a complete component class in typescript and the html template that goes with

Comment: This should work, so there's probably another part of the code you're overlooking. Are you sure that variable has the value you expect for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `attr` modifier.

```html
<input ... [attr.data-start-time]="selectedWorkOrder?.window1StartTime" [attr.data-end-time]="selectedWorkOrder?.window1endTime" />
```